# Getting Undefined. Implement with the following snippet: -> protractor + cucumber

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, yarnpkg

trying to convert my jasmine framework to cucumber framework, tried lot of options. but still getting below error

**Command**

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tags="@login"
```

and also tired with yarn, but ended up with same error

```
yarn e2e
```

**Error**

```
warnings:
1) Scenario: Login - Admin Login with 'VALID' UserName and Password - e2e/features/login.feature:6
   Step: Given I navigate to application - e2e/features/login.feature:7
   Message:
     Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
       this.Given(/^I navigate to application$/, function (callback) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         callback(null, 'pending');
       });
1 scenario (1 undefined)
1 step (1 undefined)
0m00.001s
[09:17:59] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[09:17:59] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[09:17:59] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[09:17:59] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ir-backoffice@0.11.9 e2e: `ng e2e`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

**feature file.**

login.feature

```
Feature: Login Regression Feature
  As a IR admin, I want to Login through IR Application
  So that Client can access application features

  @login
  Scenario:Login - Admin Login with 'VALID' UserName and Password
    Given I navigate to application
```

**and Step definition file**

```
import { LoginDriver } from '../../drivers/login.driver';

const loginDriver = new LoginDriver();
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { defineSupportCode } from 'cucumber';


defineSupportCode(({After, Given, Then, When}) => {

  Given(/^I navigate to application$/, function () {
   loginDriver.navigateByUrl();
  });

});
```

**and protractor.config.ts**

```
    // Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
    // https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

    // const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

    exports.config = {
      allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
      specs: [
        './e2e/features/*.feature'
      ],
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          // args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1980,1080" ]
        }
      },
      directConnect: true,
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      framework: 'custom',
      frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
      cucumberOpts: {
        require: ["./e2e/features/**/*.steps.js"],
        tags: [],
        strict: true,
        format: ["progress"],
        dryRun: false,
        // compiler: [ 'ts:ts-node']
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register"

      }
    }

;
```

Here is my folder Structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXm7G.png)

I've spent 5-6 hours to find the solution, but I couldn't get through it

Please help regarding, that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple question, you use wrong file extension at `cucumbeOpts.require`.  Should be `.ts`, not `.js`.

```
require: ["./e2e/features/**/*.steps.ts"],
```

Comment: thanks @yong for your reply, but I've tried already with `.ts` extension., but getting below error

Comment: ```at Object.<anonymous> (/e2e/features/steps/login.steps.ts:8:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Module.m._compile (e/src/index.ts:403:23)
    at Module._extensions..js```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
`

Comment: The original error: `Undefined. Implement with the following snippet` gone now.  You met the second error, it said there is a error at the line 8 of `login.steps.ts`.  Please show `login.steps.ts` and you can check it too.

Answer (score 0):

The error log itself says, It is unable to call the required step from step definition file, Be sure to check the following things,

i) Ensure Both Feature file and Step definition file, Statements are same (Ther e should not be unnecessary Spaces, Caps),

ii) Ensure You are calling exact file name in Config files,

iii) Ensure Files paths are correct.